# Not able to delete or get single user from mongoDB using Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, mongodb, axios

I am taking the email of the user from the id of the request(URL) and trying to delete/get the user for this respective email id. Basically email is an id of the users (email is unique for all the users).
The user is not deleted, and for get request, I am getting null.

**Delete by Id code:**

```
router.delete("/:id", async(req, res) => {
    try{
        console.log(req.params.id);
        var query = {email:req.params.id}
        const user = await User.deleteOne(query);
        console.log(user);
        res.status(200).json("User has been deleted...");
    }catch(err){
        res.status(404).json("User not found!");
    }
});
```

**Get user by id:**

```
router.get("/:id", async(req, res) => {
try{
    const email = req.params.id;
    console.log(email);
    const user = await User.find({email:req.params.id})
    res.status(200).json(user[0]); 
}
catch(err){
    res.status(500).json(err);
}
});
```

If I am using static email to fetch the single user, I am getting the correct output, but with variable no output.

Static example:
`const user = await User.find({email:'sita@gmail.com'})`

Comment: Can we see a sample document?  What is logged for `email` in the get route?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to fetch through email id or name etc.

I suggest use query params

**for Example**

**`For Delete:`**

```js
router.delete("/", async(req, res) => {
    try{
        var query = {email:req.query.email}
        const user = await User.deleteOne(query);
        res.status(200).json("User has been deleted...");
    }catch(err){
        res.status(404).json("User not found!");
    }
});
```

**`For Fetch`**

for single document use: `findOne`

for multi Documents use: `find`

```js
router.get("/", async(req, res) => {
try{
    const user = await User.findOne({email:req.query.email})
    res.status(200).json(user); 
}
catch(err){
    res.status(500).json(err);
}
});
```